# How to dynamically generate content of form/grid in UserControl

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have XML document

```
<fields>
  <field type="text">Firstname</field>
  <field type="text">Lastname</field>
  <field type="date">Birthday</field>
</fields>
```

(it is simple example but inside field there is declaration about some margins, size of text or TextBox and so on)

I have to generate controls like TextBox for text, some DatePicker (extended wpf) for dates according to XML document content.
I cannot generate it in code-behind and at this moment, after checking so many examples of differet things similar to my problem I am confused.

Project I am writing about has been written with use of MVVM pattern, IoC (UnityBootstrapper from Prism) and regions from Prism framework. I have been thinking to wrap TextBox/DatePicker etc. with UserControls(Views) and prism modules like TextBoxModule and inject them dynamically but I think it is not so good idea.

I am looking for some direction :/

Comment: Is there a pattern to this? Could you explain the usage? I have at least two directions you could go in, but which is more appropriate depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Yep, the usage is to collect dynamically changing data (depend on xml layouts) for printing documents. Inside app user loads the layout (example above), clicks the button with binded command to open view with grid/stackpanel filled by controls declared in xml layout. 
Every control has additional declared [meta]data like margin or some cosmetics things for the content/text on the final document (not for the view with generated controls) but at this moment i don't worry about it. 
After user fills textboxes etc. and click next button, some document will be generated and ready for printing.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so the end result is a grid with controls all over it rather than say a list of labelled fields.

I think regions and whatnot from PRISM are just going to get in the way of this and I wouldn't use any of them.

The recommended way to build dynamic UI nowadays is to use XamlReader. The Load method allows you to create UI objects from a file and the Parse method from a string.
If you were to do the same ui repeatedly then writing one file and xamlreader.load would be the way to go. If they're one offs then parse is more convenient.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
This gives you one object - I should think your grid would be best.

Since XAML is xml you can use xml to linq mechanisms to read your xml and again to write the xml nodes corresponding to controls into your string.
There are samples you can take a look at here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28797.wpf-dynamic-xaml.aspx
It's a bit pointless pasting in code from there and in any case there's a fair bit of it.
None do exactly precisely what you want but there's stuff in there is tricky to work out if you don't know how.
Eg you will need the equivalent to xmlns in there with the parsercontext. The grid will be instantiated completely separate from your existing XAML so you need to tell it to use the same sort of libraries as you do with say a window or usercontrol.

I'm not sure how representative the xml shown is, so rather than try and write something to handle those I'll give you something shows how to iterate nodes and maybe get you started.

```
        string myXMLfile =  @"d:\biz\xml.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(myXMLfile);
        XmlElement xmlRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList Fields xmlRoot.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode field in Fields)
        {
```

There are .Name and .InnerText you can work with.
There are also xmlattributes for the attributes ( obviously ).

Comment: I have been reading about XamlReader but the layout, I mean XML document where the layout of document is declared has it's own format. I cannot write out inside node like TextBox. Only the one element inside some Child tells me that the Child will be for example TextBox and it is attribute and it's value - text.

Comment: I'm suggesting you iterate the nodes using linq to xml and build the XAML string based on what each node has.

Comment: Or just system.xml